# Using COM dll with unmanaged c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I am still a bit new to Windows programming and sometimes find the documentation and tutorials I find confusing and sometimes contradictory but I hope I can make some sense and be corrected on any points I am mistaken about.
I am using an API where the documentation included is quite poor. It is made up of a number of DLLs that they envisioned would be added as a reference to VB projects (most of the users are biologists/chemists and are not very familiar with other languages, so they recommend VB). I thought they were .NET dlls at first but they cannot be registered with regasm and a tlb cannot be generated using this but can be registered with regsvr32, so I guess that means they are COM dlls...please correct me if I am wrong.

My understanding is that as this exposes the COM objects that I should be able to use this with .NET languages and unmanged c++. I have used it in C# but I would also like to use this in unmanged c++. I have seen tutorials like this:
http://cppkid.wordpress.com/2009/01/...nmanaged-code/
That import the type library but I do not have this, it was not supplied with the API. However using OLE viewer I was able to see that they were available (embedded in the dll?). I was wondering if anyone knows how I can go from this to actually using the dll in c++.

Cheers and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to achive this would be to use the `#import` directive:

`#import <mygreatlib.dll>`

There are other ways though, like using `#import` with the [ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd542719%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the entry point class of your dll, or using the [MFC type library wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06teee.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that.  I am not sure how to call the methods in the API after doing this.  Hopefully I can find a tutorial on it somewhere.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6243/Step-by-Step-Calling-C-DLLs-from-VC-and-VB-Part-2

Comment: @Shashwat Except for the link to codeproject, the rest of the URLs you posted do not apply on this scenario

Comment: When I tried importing the dll I got a number of errors of the form: c:\testuserida\debug\exploredataobjects.tlh(109) : error C3149: 'ExploreDataObjects::_DataEvents' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'
Does this mean it is actually a .NET dll?  I am ever so confused now...

Comment: Maybe you are compiling you c++ project as clr/pure?. Try removing clr support in the project properties.The fact that you got the *.tlh file means that you are actually dealing with a COM dll.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have been the problem.  I was trying something earlier using clr and I thought I changed it back.  I am trying to make use of the API as well as a c++ library.  Originally I thought I could create a managed project and use C++ interop to make use of the C++ library but now I am trying it the other way around.

Comment: Sorry for adding irrelevant link, i have removed it.

Comment: I am still having some problems with this and was wondering if someone can help.  When  look for tutorials on this I find plenty of cases where people are trying to make use of a .NET COM dll in unmanaged code, or the other way around, but I have not found anyone calling an unmanaged COM from unmanaged code.
How do I create an interface point?  I have seen two main ways of doing this for .NET COM dlls:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C
are either of these appropriate?

Comment: It makes no difference for you if the COM dll you are using was created with managed code or unmanaged code, the client code remains the same, so you can use as guide any example of a COM dll being used from unmanaged code.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I figured it out.  I was having problems due to a typo I made and never noticed.